# NoSuchMethodError when using setNavigationBarDividerColor()?

Tags: android, nosuchmethoderror, android-navigation-bar, android-window

I was trying to create a divider between the navigation bar and my app content when they are the same colour, the way that Google has been doing it with their latest Material Design 2.0 updates to their apps like Google Contacts and Google Home. I tried to do it like this:

`getWindow().setNavigationBarDividerColor(Color.GRAY);`

However, I get a `NoSuchMethodError` when trying.

I am trying to find s a way to fix this or another way of putting a divider above the navigation bar.

Here is the stack:

```
10-16 20:33:47.257 30336-30336/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.diamonddevelopment.scholarly, PID: 30336
        java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setNavigationBarDividerColor(I)V in class Landroid/view/Window; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.view.Window' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes2.dex)
            at com.diamonddevelopment.scholarly.base.BaseActivity.styleNavBar(BaseActivity.java:101)
            at com.diamonddevelopment.scholarly.base.BaseActivity.setToolbars(BaseActivity.java:78)
            at com.diamonddevelopment.scholarly.fragments.TimetableFragment.onCreateView(TimetableFragment.java:79)
            at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
            at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3273)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3229)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:620)
            at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1413)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7061)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2874)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2989)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1688)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6753)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:482)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**`setNavigationBarDividerColor()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setNavigationBarDividerColor(int))

- Shows a thin line of the specified color between the navigation bar and the app content.

The `setNavigationBarDividerColor()` method was **added in API level 28** so it will work only  in API level 28 and above

You can not use `setNavigationBarDividerColor()` method below API level 28

When you use `setNavigationBarDividerColor()` you will get a Warning  check below screenshot

[image]

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
     getWindow().setNavigationBarDividerColor(Color.GRAY)
  };
```

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer, I wonder why I didn't get a warning.

Comment: You see, I did not get a warning you did pictured in your updated answer.